# pointers and string literals

Tags: c++, pointers, string-literals

Many a times I have seen the following statements:

```
char* ch = "Hello"
cout<<ch;
```

The output I get is "**Hello**". I know that ch points to the first character of the string "Hello" and that "Hello" is a string literal and stored in read only memory. Since, ch stores the address of the first character in the string literal, so shouldn't the statement,

```
cout<<ch;
```

give the output "**the address of a character**" because, it is a pointer variable? Instead it prints the string literal itself.
Moreover, if I write this,

```
ch++;
cout<<ch;
```

It gives the output, "**ello**". And similarly, it happens with more consecutive ch++ statements too.
can anybody tell me, why does it happen?
Btw, I have seen other questions related to string literals, but all of them address the issue of "Why can't we do something like *ch='a'?
**EDIT :** I also want to ask this in reference to C, it happens in C too, if I type,

```
printf("%s",ch);
```

Why?

Comment: Can anybody please explain it in reference to C(see my edit) too?

Comment: It is determined based on the format specifier supplied with `printf()` family of functions. `%s` and `%p` will give you the string and the address of p, respectively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's overloaded version of `operator<<`

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& , const char* );
```

This overload is called whenever you use something like:-

```
char *p = "Hello";
cout << p;
```

This overload defines how to print that string rather than print the address. However, if you want to print the address, you can use,

```
cout << (void*) p;
```

as this would call another overload which just prints the address to stream:-

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& , void* );
```

Comment: In concreto it does `while (*p) cout << *p++;` outputting every char.

Answer (score 3):

Printing a char* in C++ gives you the string rather than a pointer because that's how the language is defined, and in turn because that's what makes sense and is useful.  We rarely need to print the address of a string, after all.  In terms of implementation, it can be achieved by overloading an operator:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, const char*);
```

You may find something like that in your standard library implementation, but it will actually be a template:

```
template <typename CharT>
std::basic_ostream<CharT>& operator <<(std::basic_ostream<CharT>&, const CharT*);
```

And it will probably have even more template parameters.

As for why `ch++` gives you a string starting from the second character, well, that's because incrementing a pointer advances it to the next element in the "array" it points to.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your ***edited*** question, regarding `printf()` in `c`, it is determined by the *format specifier* supplied with `printf()`. Check the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char * p = "Merry Christmas";

    printf("[This prints the string] >> %s\n", p);
    printf("[This prints the pointer] >> %p\n", p);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[sourav@broadsword temp]$ ./a.out 
[This prints the string] >> Merry Christmas
[This prints the pointer] >> 0x80484a0
[sourav@broadsword temp]$
```

for the same variable `p`, `%s` is used to print the string, whereas `%p` is used to print the `p` pointer itself.